# Gcloud topic escaping in Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to run a dataflow job through gcloud command:

```
gcloud beta dataflow jobs run test --gcs-location gs://bucket/templates/templateName --parameters query="select a.name,b.salary,a.id from table1 a join table2 b on a.id = b.id"
```

But I get an error saying:

ERROR: (gcloud.beta.dataflow.jobs.run) argument --parameters: Bad syntax for dict arg: [b.salary]. Please see `gcloud topic escaping` if you would like information on escaping list or dictionary flag values.

I saw the documentation for gcloud topic escaping but cannot figure out how to apply that here.Can somebody please help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: @jkff Can you please help me with this...

Comment: From https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/jobs/run, are you not supposed to add "=" between the argument's name and its value ? Like so `--gcs-location=gs://bucket/templates/templateName`

Comment: @ThehBarTender it works without that also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `parameters` argument takes a dictionary as its argument. As specified in `gcloud topic escaping`, you need to specify a delimiter between the dictionnary's elements, even though we only have one element here.

Therefore we can just give an arbitrary delimiter like ":", using (notice the change before `query=`):

`gcloud beta dataflow jobs run test --gcs-location gs://bucket/templates/templateName --parameters ^:^query="select a.name,b.salary,a.id from table1 a join table2 b on a.id = b.id"`

---

On an actual template (provided by google): `gcloud beta dataflow jobs run test --gcs-location=gs://dataflow-templates/wordcount/template_file --parameters ^:^query="select a.name,b.salary,a.id from table1 a join table2 b on a.id = b.id"`

This returns `INVALID_ARGUMENT: (bf23ae8a2a6f1efe): The workflow could not be created. Causes: (bf23ae8a2a6f165b): Found unexpected parameters: ['query' (perhaps you meant 'runner')]`, which shows that **we have indeed fixed the issue**: dataflow properly understands we're passing a `query` parameter. However the google template uses no such parameter and therefore throws an error, which is the expected behavior.

Comment: did you try running this? It doesn't seem to run...I'm getting a similar error.

Comment: Yes, it runs fine on my end. All I get is an obvious `PERMISSION_DENIED Template file failed to load` error since I don't actually have a template on my bucket. But the initial error is fixed. Can you tell me the precise new error you are getting ?

Comment: It's giving the exact same error as mentioned in the post. Did you try this with a template of your own?

Comment: By "in the post" you mean in your original post ? Are you saying that running the exact command I posted in my answer still gives you a `Bad syntax for dict arg: [b.salary]` error ? See my edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176575/discussion-between-the-hbar-tender-and-rish0097).

Comment: Hi...the thing you suggested worked. There was a mistake in the ValueProvider name I was passing. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a great bunch for this. For anyone still confused, here is a sample with multiple elements. The delimiter is `~`

```
gcloud dataflow jobs run <INPUT> \
--gcs-location=gs://dataflow-templates-us-central1/latest/Jdbc_to_BigQuery \
--region=northamerica-northeast1 \
--network=<INPUT> \
--subnetwork=<INPUT> \
--parameters ^~^driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver~driverJars="<INPUT>"~connectionProperties="<INPUT>"~outputTable="<INPUT>"~password="<INPUT>"~username="<INPUT>"~bigQueryLoadingTemporaryDirectory="<INPUT>"~connectionURL="<INPUT>"~query="select name, age, location from testtable"
```